# Find duplicates in list and exclude items based on another field

Tags: c#, linq

I have a C# list with 2 fields. I need to find duplicates based on `Field1` but exclude those duplicates where `Field2` is also the same for the given pair of duplicate items. In other words:

```
Field1  Field2  
-------------
0       0  
0       1
```

Should be in the result, while

```
Field1  Field2  
-------------
0       1  
0       1
```

Should not be in the result.
So far I got this:

```
dups = myList
  .AsParallel()
  .GroupBy(x => x.field1)
  .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
  .Select(x => x.Key);
```

But I don't know how to exclude based on `Field2`.

Comment: What do you mean by `where Field2 is also the same`? You mean you want to exclude the results where `Field2` is duplicated, but having same `Field1`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I try to do.

Comment: When there  are duplicated entries, do you want to keep one (one line `0   1` instead of two) or to avoid getting all of them (no line `0   1` instead of two) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much efficient, but does the job (if I understood the problem right):

```
myList.GroupBy(x=>x.field1)
      .Where(g=>g.Count()>1)
      .SelectMany(g=>g)
      .GroupBy(x=>new{x.field1,x.field2})
      .Where(g=>g.Count()==1)
      .SelectMany(g=>g);
```

For a sample of some tuples below:

```
var myList = new List<Tuple<int,int>>{
    new Tuple<int,int>(1,2),
    new Tuple<int,int>(1,2),
    new Tuple<int,int>(1,3),
    new Tuple<int,int>(1,4),
    new Tuple<int,int>(2,3),
    new Tuple<int,int>(2,4),
};
```

this returns (ran on linqpad):

[image]

Comment: Would't your `where`clause just get rid of all the entries that are duplicated, instead of keeping one of each (get rid of only duplicated entries) ? (not sure if I understood OP's request correctly)

Comment: I think OP needs all duplicates based on `field1`; but wants to exclude those which are duplicate on `field2` too, (Not sure if I understood correct.)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for creating a custom `IEqualityComparer` :

```
class MyClass {
    public int field1;
    public int field2;
}

class MyClassComparer: EqualityComparer<MyClass>
{
    public override bool Equals(MyClass x, MyClass y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return true;
        else if (x == null || x == null)
            return false;

        if (x.field1 == y.field1 && x.field2 == y.field2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(MyClass x)
    {
        int hCode = x.field1.GetHashCode() ^ x.field2.GetHashCode();
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can just add a

```
.Distinct(new MyClassComparer())
```

to the result list. somehting like (maybe need some adaptation, can't test it right now) :

```
dups = myList
  .AsParallel()
  .GroupBy(x => x.field1)
  .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
  .Select(x => x.Key)
  .ToList();

undupeds = 
  dups.Distinct(new MyClassComparer());
```

caveat: This does get rid of duplicates *after* the db query.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Fields> RemoveDuplicates(List<Fields> fields)
    {
        List<Fields> removedDuplicates = new List<Fields>();

        fields.ForEach(f =>
        {
            if (removedDuplicates.FindAll(d => 
                d.Field1 == f.Field1 && 
                d.Field2 == f.Field2).Count == 0)
            {
                removedDuplicates.Add(f);
            }
        });

        return removedDuplicates;
    }
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you're asking for, but it should create a new list which only has one instance of a "Fields" object for each duplicate in the original list.